# Blazor page, @inject directive as public to implement an interface

Tags: c#, .net, blazor

I have several pages with same "logic".
To avoid repeat code, I hardcored that logic into and Interface with implementations.
BUT this logic needs Injected Services.

If I put those injected services into Interface, I can't use @inject directive because @inject implementation don't use PUBLIC modifier (so it can't implement interface).

Example:

Interface:

```
public interface IReservaEditActions
    {
        DialogService dialogService { get;}
        ReservasService reservasService{ get;}
        NavigationManager navigationManager{ get;}
        public async Task IDoAccion((AccionReserva accion, ReservaView r) e)
        {
            var accion = e.accion;
            switch (accion)
            {
                case AccionReserva.CanDelete:
                    await IDoBorrar(e.r);
                    break;
                case AccionReserva.CanDeleteHoja:
                    await IDoBorrarHoja(e.r);
                    break;
                case AccionReserva.CanMarkNoUsado:
                    DoNoUsado(e.r);
                    break;
                case AccionReserva.CanUnMarkNoUsado:
                    DoQuitarNoUsado(e.r);
                    break;
                case AccionReserva.CanAddHoja:
                    DoAddHoja(e.r);
                    break;
                case AccionReserva.CanEditHoja:
                    DoEditHoja(e.r);
                    break;

            }

        }
[...]
```

Blazor page:

```
@page "/HojasDeRuta"
@inject NavigationManager navigationManager
@inject ReservasService reservasService
@inject DialogService dialogService
@implements IDisposable
@implements IReservaEditActions
[...]
private async Task DoAccion((AccionReserva accion,ReservaView r) e)
    {
        await (this as IReservaEditActions).IDoAccion(e);
    }

[...]
```

If I could signal @inject as public, I can reuse that Interface implementation of certain "login" accross several pages, but It seems is not posible.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code block or code behind approach.

```
@code {
    [Inject]
    public ISomeService SomeService { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works! And now I can reuse logic through impementations in interfaces

Answer (score 0):

The Interface implements the public members.  Then define an abstract base class with all the shared functionality.  Injected services and all other "private" methods/properties can be declared here as `protected`. Brian's answer shows you how to do services in the class declaration. Finally declare the real class with inheritance from the base class.

Comment: Totally agree `protected` would be a wiser choice in a base class.